# Get value from selected Checkbox value using Java Script/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get selected dynamically generated checkbox value using Javascript/jQuery.

Below the code I am using. I need to get id from selected checkbox.

```js
function GetSelectedId() {
  var array = []

  $("input:checkbox[name=type]:checked").each(function() {
    alert(array.push($(this).val()));
  });
}
```

```html
<td><input type="checkbox" name="type" id="400" />&nbsp;</td>.
<td><input type="checkbox" name="type" id="401" />&nbsp;</td>
```

Comment: no error.I need to write a java script /Jquery code for get id of selected check boxes.I Will add what i have tried.

Comment: can you also share your html

Comment: my html has around 3000 lines.My requirement is to get id from selected check box.                   For example.Getting below id values while inspect selected checkbox.              
 <td><input type="checkbox" name="type" id="400"> />&nbsp;</td>.              <td><input type="checkbox" name="type" id="401" />&nbsp;</td>

Comment: Now I need to get above id value 400 and 401 value using jQuery/Javascript.

Comment: I removed the initial html part from the question, because it is not important for it. If you think it is then you can rollback to the previous version click on edit -> go to the version before and click rollback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the inputs fields with the name *type* which are *checked* in JQuery by

```
$('input[name="type"]:checked');
```

Then you can map the id's to a new array

```
inps.map(x => x.id)
```

Hence you can use map you have to make the result of the query iterable by

```
let inps = [...$('input[name="type"]:checked')];
```

Then you can return the array in your function

```
function getSelectedId() {
  // ...
  return inps.map(x => x.id)
}
```

*Note: Function names usually starts with a lowercase letter*

```js
function getSelectedId() {

  let inps = [...$('input[name="type"]:checked')];
  return inps.map(x => x.id)
}

const arr = getSelectedId();

console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="type" id="400" checked/>&nbsp;</td>.
<td><input type="checkbox" name="type" id="401" />&nbsp;</td>
```

Comment: Thanks Alex.I have tried below way.Now i am getting values.

Comment: var checkBoxValue=[]
        $("input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function(){
            checkBoxValue.push($(this).val());
        });
        console.log(checkBoxValue)

Comment: Thanks for your effort.Now i am getting value as ["400","401"].How to split this array values? I need to pass separately this values to Ajax call.

Comment: No Alex.I need split each array value and assign to one string constant.For example var checkBoxValue1="400" and var checkBoxValue2="401".

Comment: You can use array destructuring 
[val1, val2] = array
https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destrukturierende_Zuweisung